# i want to trigger my jenkins job when a Merge Request if merged to a specific branch is a particular folder in the local machine?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, cicd, jenkins-job-dsl

In Jenkins how can I configure a Jenkins job which is triggered when I have an mr which is merged on my GitLab account, is pulled to my master branch locally, or in that specific folder when I merge a local branch to master or any specified branch???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I doubt you will find a way to manually specify all these conditions for a trigger in a Jenkins job. However, there is an effective way to achieve this.

You need to create a job that runs every time a commit is made. Within the job, define a stage and specify all of your above conditions. If any of the conditions are met, trigger your build job as a downstream job.

In order to find which files had been changed you can use `git diff` to perform a diff between your latest commit, and the commit before that. The branch name is available as an in-built variable `env.BRANCH_NAME`.

Comment: supposedly i have a folder for jenkins job ```jobhdemo```, but i want this task to trigeerend in my home directory folder ```instam```, how can i achive that with git also integrated in that job

Comment: You can wrap the stage with `dir`. Example can be found [here](https://www.baeldung.com/ops/jenkins-pipeline-change-to-another-folder)